# What is the meaning of this license term as "GPL (>= 3) | file LICENCE"?

Tags: python, r

When I ran package information in Anaconda for package r-copula, I got following text. I am trying to understand the license from the string "GPL (>= 3) | file LICENCE".  What does the pipe bar "|" mean? What is "file LICENSE"?

```
r-copula 0.999_19.1 r36h6115d3f_0
---------------------------------
file name   : r-copula-0.999_19.1-r36h6115d3f_0.tar.bz2
name        : r-copula
version     : 0.999_19.1
build       : r36h6115d3f_0
build number: 0
size        : 7.2 MB
license     : GPL (>= 3) | file LICENCE
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/r-copula-0.999_19.1-r36h6115d3f_0.tar.bz2
md5         : 503da99a957dc695e5c3c295130c3ae1
timestamp   : 2019-05-16 06:33:01 UTC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as in R or Python programming, the bar means "or". The package includes a file named `LICENCE`, and you can use it under your choice of a GPL license version 3 or higher, or under the license specified in the `LICENCE` file.

If you view the `copula` package page [on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=copula), the LICENCE gives a link to the [license file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/LICENCE). In this particular case, it doesn't actually seem to be a different choice, my reading of it is that is says the same thing: GPL license version 3 or greater. (But of course, not a lawyer, don't take  my word for it---read it for yourself.)

---

The license field is documented in the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Licensing) manual. In the relevant section, they say:

> Alternatives are indicated *via* vertical bars.